# How to select the row where the date is null or max date for that group

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with multiple columns, but I will make it easy and just use three.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPTBL(
    empl_id     varchar(8),
    empl_no     varchar(6),
    sep_dt      date
);

INSERT INTO TEMPTBL
VALUES
    ('IS000001', '112233', NULL),
    ('00418910', '112233', '1/1/2019');
```

What I am trying to get is the row where either the sep_dt is null or the row where that has the max sep_dt grouped by the empl_no field.  So in the case of my example, it would be that first row, 'IS000001' (I just want the select to return the empl_id).  Say the Null was '6/8/2018' instead, then I would want to return '00418910'.

I have tried, but I know it is wrong because you can't use max like that:

```
SELECT   empl_id
FROM     TEMPTBL empl
WHERE    empl_no = '112233' AND (
             sep_dt IS NULL OR
             MAX(sep_dt)
         )
```

I know it must include a group by or maybe a join.  So I came up with this:

```
SELECT   empl_id
FROM     TEMPTBL
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT   empl_no, max(sep_dt) as sep_dt
             FROM     TEMPTBL
             WHERE    empl_no = '112233'
             GROUP BY empl_no
         ) emp ON TEMPTBL.empl_no = emp.empl_no AND TEMPTBL.sep_dt = emp.sep_dt
```

This will give me the row with the date in it, not the one with the null value.  So it will work if all the sep_dt fields have values, but if one in NULL, it doesnt work, because i want the row with the null value.  What am I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can simply use `ROW_NUMBER` with a special `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY empl_no
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN sep_dt IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, sep_dt DESC
    ) AS rn
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6015b48dd9cb03a5ce8147846ec6ee3d)

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below - use `group by` with 2 fields `empl_id,empl_no`

```
SELECT empl_id,empl_no, max(sep_dt) as sep_dt
FROM TEMPTBL
group by empl_id,empl_no
```